# Difference between CodeFile.cs and Class.cs in silverlight

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, templates, file-type

I am a novice in silverlight. I tried to add some random files in a silverlight project. I found two types (`CodeFile and Class`), both having an extension .cs.

Can anyone please tell me the difference between these two or when to use which of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the code file and Class file are having the same extension but when you actually add it to the solution

**class file comes with some autogenerated code like this**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace defaultproject
{
    public class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

**code file comes with no code, just empty file and you need to add what you want**

just try to add both types of the file in your project you will get the difference easily...

Comment: Thanks, but is there any  situation based/usability difference? Or the only difference is this template?

Comment: @Rain- there is no usability difference just template diffence because both create cs file ...